How to check if the time is already passed monday and the refresh is not made
I want to perform a refresh on the users appointments when its monday, but my problem is I cannot check if the current time is passed monday, if the user does not open the app on the refresh time(in my case monday).
this is how i start the refresh but the remainingTime is never negative
void startWeeklyRefresh() async{
    remainingTime = _calculateTimeUntilNextMonday();
    if (remainingTime.isNegative) {
      await _performWeeklyReset();
    } else {
      Timer(remainingTime,() async{ 
        await _performWeeklyReset();
      });
    }
  }

this is how i calculate the remaining time until monday
Duration _calculateTimeUntilNextMonday() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(const Duration(hours: 3)); // Adjusting to UTC+3 for Turkey Time
  int targetDay = DateTime.monday;
  int daysUntilMonday = (targetDay - now.weekday + 7) % 7;
  if (daysUntilMonday == 0 && (now.hour > 0 || now.minute > 0 || now.second > 0)) {
    daysUntilMonday = 7;
  }
  DateTime nextTargetDay = now.add(Duration(days: daysUntilMonday)).copyWith(
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0
  );
  return nextTargetDay.difference(now);
}

So if the user does not open the app on monday the refresh does not happen because remainingTime automatically is being added 7 days, so skips the refresh and goes to next refresh time.

I was getting facing the same scenario for delete post after 24 hours. Mostly backend developers manage this thing via cron jobs. But we were using the firebase so we did this. We had a collection of "posts" when ever any user get posts we checked the post creating date and time for all posts and performed the delete query on that, after that we filtered the post for user according to user id.

use some background task plugin

@CsabaMihaly i am trying workmanager to run tastks in the background right now, thanks for the suggestion !!
